# Как реализовать НОД трех чисел с помощью метода Стейна? Очень слаб в арифметике. Нашел пример для двух чисел, не могу разобраться

Tags: c#, алгоритм

```
        if (a == b)
        {
            return a;
        }
            
        if (a == 0)
        {
            return b;
        }
            
        if (b == 0)
        {
            return a;
        }

        if ((~a & 1) != 0)
        {
            if ((b & 1) != 0)
            {
                return GetGcdByStein(a >> 1, b);
            }
            else
            {
                return GetGcdByStein(a >> 1, b >> 1) << 1;
            }                    
        }

        if ((~b & 1) != 0)
        {
            return GetGcdByStein(a, b >> 1);
        }

        if (a > b)
        {
            return GetGcdByStein((a - b) >> 1, b);
        }
        
        return GetGcdByStein((b - a) >> 1, a);
```

Comment: Есть для двух? Замечательно! `НОД(a,b,c)=HOД(HOД(a,b),c)`

Comment: Но как это реализовать, не понятно. Есть какие-то ресурсы где можно ознакомится с этим алгоритмом?

Comment: Два вызова вашей функции — что непонятно? Для двух можете найти? Найдите. Затем возьмите найденное и найдите НОД для этого найденного и третьего числа. Это и будет НОД для всех трех чисел.

Comment: Выглядит не как метод, а как просто кусок кода. Типы переменных и их значения неизвестны.